# Pass values to nested functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have

```
function Outer(x, y){
     var X = x;
     this.x = x;

      $('#div1').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index, values){
           $(values).text(x); //x is undefined
           $(values).text(X); //X is undefined
      });
}
```

How to pass the values to the inner functions?

Comment: Both capital and lower case x will work.

Comment: Setting the `.text()` of an `<input>` element makes no sense. You have to set the value via `.val()`.

Comment: Show us how you call `Outer`, please. Very likely, [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)`.x` is a grave mistake.

Comment: LOL. I love it. Somebody down-voted the question just because they didn't  understand it. "Aaaaargh. Experiencing confusion. Must smash."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: all JavaScript functions have access to variables defined on their parent scope.  see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) for more.

Second: 'this' does not refer to 'itself' as you are using it, it refers to the call site of the function in question.

So in your case, all you need to do is

```
function Outer(x, y) {
  $('#div1').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index, values){
       $(values).text(x);
  });
}
```

and then call Outer with values of x and y

```
Outer(2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simply `x`:

```
function Outer(x, y){
  $('#div1').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index, values){
       $(values).text(x);
  });
}
```

Because the inner function has access to the scope of the outer function.

If `x` is `undefined`, then you are passing `undefined` to `Outer`.

Comment: The inner function access to the variables passed into the outer function.